# C# private function, IncrementArray

Tags: c#

Can someone please explain in layman's terms the workings of this C# code?

```
for (int pos = 0; pos < EncryptedData.Length; pos += AesKey.Length);
{
    Array.Copy(incPKGFileKey, 0, PKGFileKeyConsec, pos, PKGFileKey.Length);

    IncrementArray(ref incPKGFileKey, PKGFileKey.Length - 1);
}

private Boolean IncrementArray(ref byte[] sourceArray, int position)
{
    if (sourceArray[position] == 0xFF)
    {
        if (position != 0)
        {
            if (IncrementArray(ref sourceArray, position - 1))
            {
                sourceArray[position] = 0x00;
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    else
    {
        sourceArray[position] += 1;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to port an app to Ruby but I'm having trouble understanding how the IncrementArray function works.

Comment: In layman's terms, what don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

`IncrementArray` increments all entries of a byte array, with any overflow being added to the previous index, unless it's index 0 already.
The entire thing looks like some kind of encryption or decryption code. You might want to look for additional hints on which algorithm is used, as this kind of code is usually not self-explaining.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try that out. I would upvote you but I don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like a big-endian addition algorithm:

Let's say you've got a long (64 bit, 8 byte) number:

```
var bigNumber = 0x123456FFFFFFFF;
```

But for some reason, we've got it coming to us as a byte array in Big-endian format:

```
// Get the little endian byte array representation of the number: 
// [0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0x56 0x34 0x12]
byte[] source = BitConverter.GetBytes(bigNumber);

// BigEndian-ify it by reversing the byte array
source = source.Reverse().ToArray();
```

So now you want to add one to this "number" in it's current form, while maintaining any carrys/overflows like you would in normal arithmetic:

```
// increment the least significant byte by one, respecting carry
// (as it's bigendian, the least significant byte will be the last one)
IncrementArray(ref source, source.Length-1);

// we'll re-little-endian-ify it so we can convert it back
source = source.Reverse().ToArray();

// now we convert the array back into a long
var bigNumberIncremented = BitConverter.ToInt64(source, 0);

// Outputs: "Before +1:123456FFFFFFFF"
Console.WriteLine("Before +1:" + bigNumber);      

// Outputs: "After +1:12345700000000"
Console.WriteLine("After +1:" + bigNumberIncremented);
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So is one added to each element in the array and then one added to the least significant byte? Or is it just adding one to the least significant byte?